# setting GEM_HOME in Bourne shell

Tags: shell

I'm trying to execute a bootup script (to start a Thin server) on a server using an interface called Virtualmin.  I'm able to execute the commands with no problem using bash via PuTTY.  I have to use Virtualmin, though, in order to have the commands execute on bootup, and I was having problems that I think were the result of Virtualmin not having my environmental variables available to it.  Virtualmin uses Bourne shell, and I'm trying to set GEM_HOME and it's not working.

The error I'm getting is as follows:

```
/sbin/sh: GEM_HOME=/users/home/dquirk/gems: not found
```

Here are the commands I'm attempting to send . . . I'm thinking there's something wrong with the notation I'm using to try to set GEM_HOME:

```
GEM_HOME=/users/home/dquirk/gems
export GEM_HOME
/users/home/dquirk/gems/bin/thin start -c /users/home/dquirk/domains/quirkeweb.net/rails/clee -p 10671 -d -e production -a 127.0.0.1 -P /users/home/dquirk/var/run/thin-10671.pid
```

Comment: Acting like it wants to execute the first line. Do you have a #! line at the start of your file? What does `bash --version` show?  uname -a?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out . . . this is on a shared server, and the Virtualmin interface for adding bootup action commands is in the context of a Bourne shell where the user cannot change any environment variables.  I created a bash script that changed the needed variables and executed the Thin start command and then put a bash command to load that script as the bootup action command and that worked.